# Unity how to add a fade transition after hitting play button?

Tags: unity-game-engine, new-operator, fadein, fade, fadeout

I want to make my scene transition with a fade after hitting the "play" button I created. Currently when you hit the play button it transitions to the next game scene. I want to implement a fade during the transition.

[Play Button Scene Transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRCwP.png)

I already made the fade animation clip.

[Fade Animation clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4azqm.png)

Comment: So what are you doing to apply the fade?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It depends what you want the fade to look like. A simple one could be to use a screen space overlay canvas with an image on 100% stretch and use a coroutine to fade in & out the alpha of the texture. Another way would be to use screen space effects e.g. the vignette in the post processing stack. Another would be to use a custom shader.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling LoadScene immediately, perhaps you could run a fade-out animation and Load the next scene after the animation has finished, then play a fade-in animation when the next scene loads.